# Mongoose Plugin - schema.add to Subschema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am writing a mongoose plugin that involves adding a elements to the subschema. I was thinking it would be quite straightforward, but I've been trying unsuccessfully for a few days now.

Below is a simplification of the schema:

```
var inheritables = require('./inheritables.server.module.js');

var OuFieldTypeSchema = new Schema({
   name: String,
   desc: String
});
var OuFieldType = mongoose.model('OuFieldType', OuFieldTypeSchema);

var OuSchema = new Schema({
   name: String,
   fieldTypes: [OuFieldTypeSchema],
});

OuSchema.plugin(inheritables, {inherit: ['fieldTypes']});
mongoose.model('Ou', OuSchema);
```

Within the body of my Mongoose Plugin, I'd like to iterate over the "inherit" array and add the following to the schemas that represent each of these elements in the Ou schema;

A simplification of my plugin is as follows:

```
var _ = require('lodash');

module.exports = exports = function(schema, options) {
   _.each(options.inherit, function(currItemSchema){
      var addToSchema = {inheritedFrom: {name: String}};

      //Really want to add this to the OuFieldTypeSchema represented by the fieldTypes element array.
      schema.add(addToSchema, currItemSchema + ".");
   });
});
```

Note that the second parameter of add() adds a prefix, but this doesn't work.

I've also tried:

```
_.each(options.inherit, function(currItemSchema){
    var addToSchema = {};
    addToSchema[currItemSchema] = {inheritedFrom: {name: String}};
    schema.add(addToSchema);
});
```

The expected behaviour here is that elsewhere in my plugin, I have a method that sets the inheritedFrom schema. No error is received when the item is set, but the resulting output never sees the inheritedFrom elements.

I am currently adding inheritedFrom to each subschema that is used by OuFieldType, but the above is a simplification and is not very DRY.

I'm new to Node.JS - any pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.